# how to send email use nodemailer on local host postfix mail server with SSL

Tags: ssl, localhost, digital-ocean, nodemailer, postfix-mta

I have set up postfix email server on my DigitalOcean cloud server. Now I want to send email from my program using nodeMailer.  I try this setting and success

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                host: "localhost", // hostname
                secure: false, // use SSL
                port: 25, // port for secure SMTP,
               
                  tls: {
                     
                      rejectUnauthorized: false
                  }
              });
```

the email were sent in the spam folder on the target recipient Email address.So I think maybe secure:false is reason. So how can I enable SSL?

Comment: There are many reasons for email going to SPAM. If you are sending email to others on port 25, then you should setup Reverse DNS, SPF, DMARC, DKIM, etc as a minimum. There are many documents/articles on the Internet that describe how to set up email servers (entire books). More articles on why you should NOT send emails with your own servers and instead, use an email service. As written your question cannot be answered with facts, only suggestions and guesses.

Comment: thank you , I will search those resources